# Unable to login using selenium in java

Tags: java, java-8, selenium-chromedriver

Facing a peculiar problem using selenium. Unable to login from login form using selenium. It is redirecting to error page when it clicks on submit button. When the submit button is pressed manually using the very same credentials, it is able to login and redirects to required page.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your Java code and login page code. Also, which version of Selenium and chrome, do you use?